# How do I get a volatile function argument working?

Tags: c++, volatile

I am completely unexperienced in C++, I use C all the time. In my recent hobby project I need to mix in a C++ library with my C code thus forcing me to have a C++ main.cpp.

I am right now meddling my C code to compile as C++. This even works pretty well except for one problem I simply cannot solve.

This is an interrupt service incrementing my unix time variable every second and also doing a conversion into spli-up time format afterwards. Since this happens in an interrupt I set the variables as volatile.

```
volatile time_t UNIX_TIME = 0;
volatile struct tm TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME;  

if (htim == &htim2){
    UNIX_TIME++;
    TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME = *localtime(&UNIX_TIME);
}
```

From library time.h:

```
struct tm *localtime (const time_t *_timer);
```

With `gcc` this compiles flawless.

`g++` is a different story. It gives me the error:

> error: passing 'volatile tm' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

I tried multiple casts and stuff, the only way this starts working by itself is when I drop **both** volatile qualifiers. But I don't want that.

What is the correct way to get this working? I am out of ideas.

Comment: "I tried multiple casts and stuff" - which casts, and what stuff?

Comment: You should not be using `localtime` in an ISR - it isn't threadsafe.  Use `localtime_r` instead.

Comment: @underscore_d The usual stuff which is enough to convince gcc, but g++ sees right through me ;-)
I tried for example `TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME = (volatile struct tm)*localtime((const time_t*)&UNIX_TIME);`
Just trying to cast things that they will fit, but this doens't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the time first into a non-volatile instance:

```
time_t t = UNIX_TIME;
tm local = *localtime(&t);
TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME.tm_sec   = local.tm_sec;
TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME.tm_min   = local.tm_min;
TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME.tm_hour  = local.tm_hour;
TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME.tm_mday  = local.tm_mday;
TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME.tm_mon   = local.tm_mon;
TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME.tm_year  = local.tm_year;
TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME.tm_wday  = local.tm_wday;
TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME.tm_yday  = local.tm_yday;
TIME_CUR_LOCALTIME.tm_isdst = local.tm_isdst;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will give it a try to see if only that would work.
I am not sure but I have a feeling this should not be needed here. The example I posted is the only interrupt-driven change of the variable. So out of perspective of my example the variable is not volatile, just for all the rest of the program it is.
Is it really needed to copy the variable into a local non-volatile copy then?

Comment: @nEmai I don't get what you mean. In the example, the variable is volatile.

Comment: Yes it is. But when I think of why I use volatile-qualifier I think "Because I have a variable that could be changed by interrupts". But if I have a look at the same variable from inside the interrupt then it is (to the interrupt routine) not volatile, because it'll always behave like the interrupt routine wants it to.
On the other hand, the routine being interrupted by the interrupt sees a change of the variable before and after the interrupt came, so from that perspective it really is volatile. You understand what I mean? :-)

Comment: @nEmai A volatile is volatile. Volatility doesn't change depending on whether the program is executed from an interrupt or not. The C++ language does not acknowledge the existence of interrupts (other than mentioning by passing).

Comment: This is correct, I am sorry that I couldn't make my point clear in an easy way. I am trying to evaluate between two ways to go. Either being your option, which is lets call it a software mechanism by copying etc to avoid problems with variables that could change, or to just go and say "hey, knowing the program, at this specifing line of code I can assume, this variable is never volatile, thus a simple cast of some sort would be good to go." This is the direction I am trying to explain. What do you think?

Comment: @nEmai I think that C++ says that pretending volatile to not be volatile results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your solution fixes my problem for now, but I will probably revisit this some time. I somehow don't feel happy with how it is solved with the copying. But I still thank you very much for your comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

Neither the C Standard nor the C++ Standard makes any attempt to distinguish between objects which will be modified in ways a compiler would have no reason to expect, those which will only be written in ways the compiler understands but might also be read in ways it would have no reason to expect, and those which, while declared `volatile`, will in fact never be accessed in ways the compiler wouldn't expect (the latter situation may arise with libraries that will sometimes be used in systems where things are accessed via outside means and sometimes used in systems where they aren't).  All non-atomic objects that may be accessed in ways the compiler wouldn't expect must be qualified `volatile`, and because--from the Standard's point of view--all objects that are qualified `volatile` might be read or written in arbitrary outside means, any access to such an object without a `volatile` qualifier invokes Undefined Behavior, *without regard for whether any outside access actually occurs*.  The authors of the Standard probably recognized that since people wishing to sell compilers would handle such cases sensibly without regard for whether they are required to do so, there was no need for the Standard to address such cases.  Not all compiler writers, however, are bound by that principle.

The best way to achieve the behavior at issue here would probably be to copy `UNIX_TIME` to a couple of ordinary objects, ensuring that they match and repeating the read attempts if not, and then pass the address of that to any functions that would need the address of an object holding the time.  As noted elsewhere, one should avoid functions like `localtime` that use static buffers, use a function like `localtime_r`, but what's important if one wants to shut up the compiler is to copy the object somewhere else before use.